# Job queue system

Tags: python, console

I'm doing a side project at work and I consider it as a learning opportunity more than work itself, but it does hold a purpose if I can complete it. Anyway, I'll post the code, what it actually does and hopefully people can critique/improve what I've done.

```
os.system("bjobs -u all| awk ' NF>1' > file")

lines = open('file', 'r').readlines()
del lines[0]
open('file', 'w').writelines(lines)

source = open("file")                           
out = open("file1", "w")                              
for line in source:                             

        out.write(line.split(" ")[0] + "\n")            

out.close()
source.close()
```

This code does 2 parts. Firstly the `bjobs -u all| awk ' NF>1' > file` will print this to a file (plus however many jobs are running):

> ```
> JOBID   USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME   SUBMIT_TIME
> 111111  ######   ###   ###        ######     comp113     ########   Mar 27 12:50
>                                              comp113
>                                              comp113
>                                              comp113
> 222222  ######   ###   ###        ######     comp114     ########   Mar 27 12:50
>                                              comp114
>                                              comp114
>                                              comp114
> ```

Then remove the first line of the file ("JOBID USER STAT" etc) as this isn't needed.

Then strip the additional "comp113" lines away (this is done using the `awk` command to remove any lines that don't contain more than 1 field - maybe it's a bad idea mixing shell commands to format text within Python) leaving just:

> ```
> 111111  ######   ###   ###        ######     comp113     ########   Mar 27 12:50
> 222222  ######   ###   ###        ######     comp114     ########   Mar 27 12:50
> ```

From this, extract just the JOBID and store it within a separate file for later use (this is done by deleting any characters after the first whitespace in the line).

Mainly I'm just looking at maybe how I can tidy the code up and improve on anything I've done. I do plan on commenting the code when I get around to it. Anything that I've left unexplained please do ask and I'll do my best to explain. There is a lot more to this project which I plan on asking questions about in the future! Just didn't want to get ahead of myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I'm having a major doubt:** should I give you the same advice I gave you the last time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9806512/1132524)? Would you follow them this time? Or there was something not clear?

Well, I'll try my best.

### Don't use [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.system)

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Quoting from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess):

> This module intends to replace several other, older modules and functions, such as:
>
> ```
> os.system
> os.spawn*
> ```

### Use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#next) to skip the header

file ibjects are iterable, so to skip the header usually one does:

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        # start to work on the lines here
```

But I'd say that you won't need that one if you don't really need to have the file `file` on your hard disk.

### Check the output

It seems that you don't really need the file `file` to exist, so you could just check the output of your command with [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Notice that `subprocess.check_output()` will *Run command with arguments and return its output **as a byte string***. So you'll have to call the [`.decode()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method on it. If you don't have any idea of what I'm talking about take a look at the doc [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range).

### Use the `with` statement

```
with open("file1", "w") as output:
    # ...
```

### `.split()` vs. `.split(" ")`

Those two have different behaviours:

```
>>> s = 'This is        a test\tstring'
>>> s.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
>>> s.split(" ")
['This', 'is', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', 'test\tstring']
```

`.split()` will split multiple spaces and tabs too.

### You don't need `awk`

After checking the output just skip the line that you don't want:

```
cmd_output = subprocess.check_call(...).decode()
with open('file1.txt') as output_file:
    for line in cmd_outpu.split('\n')[1:]:    # [1:] will skip the header
        splitted_line = line.split()
        if len(splitted_line) > 1:
            output_file.write(splitted_line[0] + '\n')
```

You could obviously do it without decoding and working with bytes, but this way it's more clear to start with.

Comment: I literally only used your previous answer to finish the problem I was having (which you did thank you). Now I'm looking to tidy my code up (funnily I found this website through your profile) and was already applying some comments in your previous answer and now you've gave me some more help so I do appreciate your effort! I can post the rest of the code if it'll help make sense of what I'm trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @AshleyJohnKent: Happy to help :)